# Java - Encoding message to String

Tags: java, rest, encryption, httprequest, rsa

I'm trying to implement my own version of authorization for HTTP requests. Now I'm facing a problem that I don't know how to resolve.

As shown in code below, I'm encrypting String message using RSA algorithm. But the problem is that as a result I'm getting object of class `SealedObject`. I need to have the possibility to use this encrypted string as header - for now using REST client like Postman. So, my question is: How can I parse `SealedObject` to `String`? Or what should I do to encrypt the message to `String`? Is this even possible?

```
KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
KeyPair keyPair = kpg.generateKeyPair();

String message = "Secret message";

Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keyPair.getPublic());

SealedObject encryptedMessage = new SealedObject(message, cipher);
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: use the serialization interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the first thing that comes to mind is:

SealedObject is a Serializable Object which means you can convert it to bytes and then transform it to String using Base64:
something like this:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutput out = null;
try {
  out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);   
  out.writeObject(sealedObject);
  out.flush();
  byte[] yourBytes = bos.toByteArray();
  String base64StringHeader = Base64.encodeBase64String(yourBytes);
} finally {
  try {
    bos.close();
  } catch (IOException ex) {
    // ignore close exception
  }
}
```

and then when you receive your request do something like this:

```
byte[] backToBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(base64StringHeader);
ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(backToBytes);
ObjectInput in = null;
try {
  in = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
  SealedObject = in.readObject(); 
  ...
} finally {
  try {
    if (in != null) {
      in.close();
    }
  } catch (IOException ex) {
    // ignore close exception
  }
```

}